# Detecting NOTE 5 via USB from Mirrorlink QT Simulator

Tags: mirrorlink

I'm trying to link Samsung Note 5 with Mirrorlink activated with Mirrorlink 1.1 QT Simulator in Ubuntu 15.10.
I receive in Debug Window a series of message:

```
12:55:27:004 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:32:033 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:37:063 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:42:091 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:47:121 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:52:140 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:55:57:169 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
12:56:02:189 (CON) Send Ml Command: Success - Send to USB device 04E8:685D
```

But Mirrorlink Simulator screen shows
"Start Mirrolink on the Mobile Device" 
as if the mobile is not detected.
How can I check if anything is wrong and right using Mirrorlink QT Simulator with my Note 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in Qt 4.8 which may cause some Linux kernels to not correctly work with Qt’s QUdpSocket implementation. There is a bug reported, but it won’t get fixed.

The Qt Client has been developed and tested for 12.04 LTS. It needs a 2.3 Linux Kernel

Answer (score 1):

Newer Linux 3.13 kernels should work now without a problem.

The following kernels are known to work with MirrorLink devices (tested with HTC One M8):

- 3.13.0-88-generic
- 3.13.0-86-generic
- 3.13.0-83-generic